# AWS EC2 SSH Keys

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, ssh

I have a question to ask about AWS EC2. I created an EC2 instance before with a ppk file and associated my EC2 instance with that PPK file on Putty.

Thereafter, I created a separate EC2 instance with additional storage and I tried to associate my ppk file with this instance too.

However, When I ssh onto Putty, it gives me this error

```
Using username "ec2-storage".
Server refused our key
```

Is it because once a EC2 instance is using a keypair I cant use it for another EC2 instance? However, if this is the case why does the AWS console give us the option to choose an existing key pair?

Any advice?

Adrian

Comment: You can use a keypair for as many ec2 instances as you want. Are you sure you are using the right private key aws sent to you when you created the keypair to ssh?

Comment: I managed to get it working. the username was Ec2-user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are launching an Amazon EC2 instance based on the Amazon Linux AMI, the username is `ec2-user`.

Comment: Managed to do it. But is there anyway to change the username to something else?

Comment: That's a Linux-related question. Just Google for "Linux add user". You'll want to create the user, create their home directory and copy their personal keypair into their directory under `.ssh/authorized_keys`.